# A clarification on modular multiplication.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $P,Q$ be primes in $[2^{n-1},2^n]$.

Supposing we know $p=mP\bmod T$ and $q=nQ\bmod T$ for some prime $T$ in $[n^d,2n^d]$ ($d>0$ is fixed) for some $m,n\in\Bbb Z$ and $p$ is prime. Note $p,q<T<pq$ holds.

Say now we multiply $PQ$ by $mn'$ and take $\bmod T$ to get $mn'PQ\equiv c\bmod T$.

My question is: are there more than one $r'$ (say $r',r''$) in $[0,T]$ such that $$c+r'T=pq'$$
$$c+r''T=pq''$$ holds for some integers (not primes) $q',q''$? That is can there be more than one $r'$ in $[0,T]$ such that $p|(c+r'T)$ and $p|(c+r''T)$ for each such $r',r''$?

Say $r'$ and $r''$ are two such integers then $p(q'-q'')=(r'-r'')T$ holds and so since $T>p,q',q''$ and $T>p,|q-q'|$ seems to imply this is impossible. Am I right?